# Dynamic MEL Shelf Scripting

Tags: maya, mel

I’m making a custom shelf.  I’ve got drag and drop functionality working, but I need to figure out how to get a list of items in the shelf and also the order, dynamically.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the same problem, but maybe [this](http://tech-artists.org/t/dynamic-maya-shelf-mel/1413) it is a starting point.

Comment: haha thanks for the link!  It actually is the answer, it's my post!

Comment: the link is broken "Oops! That page doesn’t exist or is private."